# Iterating through excel rows skips a number EVERY TIME it passes through foreach loop, pulling wrong cell values. Why

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have this method that takes two string parameters and iterates through each row in an Excel sheet to find a match in two columns. when it finds a match it returns the row number so that number can be used to determine (in another method) which row to UPDATE.

```
    public int IterateRows(string f, string l)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(locationAndNameOfExcelFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

        //Iterate the rows in the used range
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows)
        {
            var familyNameCellValue = row.Cells[row.Row, 2].Value2.ToString();
            var firstNameCellValue = row.Cells[row.Row, 3].Value2.ToString();;

            if (f == familyNameCellValue && firstNameCellValue == l)
            {
                return row.Row;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The issue is, when debugging through each foreach iteration,when hovering over the "row.Row" values, I notice that the are correct (as in NOT skipping an Excel row). I know for a fact, thought, that the values for a certain Cell value should be something else. It seems to skip to such that

- if "row.Row" reads 2, it has the value of the 3rd row cell,
- if "row.Row" reads 3, it has the value of the 5rd row cell,
- if "row.Row" reads 4, it has the value of the 7rd row cell,
- if "row.Row" reads 5, it has the value of the 9rd row cell,
- if "row.Row" reads 6, it has the value of the 11rd row cell,
- etc...,
  If the row I seek is an odd number, it will obviously return "row.Row"

can someone explain why it is skipping?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it (it's a bit dirty and I still do not understand why it skips a row in each foreach iteration, but I added a "var i" to track the row that I am in. given the spread in each iteration, it raises by one. so I just set a new "var r" to represent the row based upon a ternary operator. since the first row is the header it always seems to work

```
    public int IterateRows(string f, string l)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(locationAndNameOfExcelFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

        var rowsRanged = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows;
        var i = 1;
        //Iterate the rows in the used range
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in rowsRanged)
        {
            var r = row.Row > 1 ? row.Row - i : row.Row;
            var familyNameCellValue = row.Cells[r, 2].Value2.ToString();
            var firstNameCellValue = row.Cells[r, 3].Value2.ToString();
            //var familyNameCellValue = row.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToString();
            //var firstNameCellValue = row.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString();

            if (f == familyNameCellValue && firstNameCellValue == l)
            {
                return i - 1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spent the whole morning trying to find the solution to the same problem, and it feels like a little addition could still be useful. Your mistake is that you're addressing the cells in a row like cells in the whole range, whereas a row is just a plain horizontal line of cells: Cell[1,1], Cell[1,2] ... no matter how big was this row's original index in the table.

So, instead of this

```
var familyNameCellValue = row.Cells[row.Row, 2].Value2.ToString();
```

just write it this way:

```
var familyNameCellValue = row.Cells[1, 2].Value2.ToString();
```

Works like a swiss watch for me.